# Is it possible to use CORBA reliably from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, corba

I'm looking at possibly moving from Java servlets which interact with C++ via CORBA calls to a NodeJS backend but I've only found two incomplete projects to implement CORBA on nodejs. Is there something about the NodeJS architecture that makes it incompatible with CORBA RPC? If not is there some resource for getting started with CORBA in NodeJS?

Comment: For anyone voting as off topic would you let me know what SE community you feel the topic is suited for? It didn't seem to fit in Software Engineering  since I'm looking for an implementation

Comment: I have the same question, please tell me if you find any interesting solution with nodejs, thank you

Comment: From my research it looks like you would need to write the entire interface yourself, however I'm still holding out hope that I've misunderstood. Currently learning C so I'm a long way from understanding fully what is required